# Why am I getting error number 150 from this MySQL statement?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, key

I've checked that the data type of referenced table is exactly same as foreign key on this table below, and I'm still not sure? The SQL document isn't exactly clear.

```
P_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
price DECIMAL(5,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
descr TEXT,
imgName VARCHAR(50),
stock INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PG_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (P_id),
FOREIGN KEY (PG_id) REFERENCES prodGroups(PG_id)
```

Comment: If PG_id is the foreign key why have set it to AUTO INCREMENT?

Comment: Was a typo, the AUTO_INCREMENT was not meant to be there, nor the NOT NULL. However, errors still occur.

Answer (score 0):

There could only be one AUTO INCREMENT column. So, I guess, one in the `PG_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL` is just a copy/paste went wrong :)

Comment: It should. Whats your mysql version?